# Find index of duplicate rows in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to find the index of all duplicate rows in an excel file and add them to a list which will be handled later.

```
unwantedRows = []
Row = []
item = ""

for index, row in enumerate(ws1.iter_rows(max_col = 50), start = 1):
  for cell in row:
    if cell.value:
      item += cell.value
  if item in Row:
    unwantedRows.append(index)
  else:
    Row.append(item)
```

However this fails to work. It only indexes rows that are completely empty. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should look at the code that detects duplicate rows. It looks pretty ropey to me. Also, it's not a good idea to use the same name with a different spelling for different objects. In this case it's not very clear how the code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unwantedRows = []
Rows = []

for index, row in enumerate(ws1.iter_rows(max_col = 50), start = 1):
  sublist = []
  for cell in row:
    sublist.append(cell.value)

  if sublist not in Rows:
    Rows.append((sublist))
  else:
    unwantedRows.append(index)
```

Comment: Why put the list in a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Without a tuple:

```
row_numbers_to_delete = []
rows_to_keep = []
for row in ws.rows:
    working_list = []
    for cell in row:
        working_list.append(cell.value)
    if working_list not in rows_to_keep:
        rows_to_keep.append(working_list)
    else:
        row_numbers_to_delete.append(cell.row)
for row in row_numbers_to_delete:
    ws.delete_rows(
        idx=row,
        amount=1
    )
```